# Java: Static initialization

Tags: java, static

can you explain me which is the difference between:

```
public class Test {

    public static final Person p;

    static {
        p = new Person();
        p.setName("Josh");
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Test {

    public static final Person p = initPerson();

    private static Person initPerson() {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("Josh");
        return p;
    }

}
```

I have always used the second one, but is there any difference with an static initializer block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are of course technical differences (you could invoke the static method multiple times within your class if you wanted, you could invoke it via reflection, etc) but, assuming you don't do any of that trickery, you're right -- the two approaches are effectively identical.

I also prefer the method-based approach, since it gives a nice name to the block of code. But it's almost entirely a stylistic approach.

As Marko points out, the method-based approach also serves to separate the two concerns of creating the Person, and assigning it to the static variable. With the static block, those two things are combined, which can hurt readability if the block is non-trivial. But with the method approach, the method is responsible *solely* for creating the object, and the static variable's initializion is responsible *solely* for taking that method's result and assigning it to the variable.

Taking this a bit further: if I have two static fields, and one depends on the other, then I'll declare two methods, and have the second method take the first variable as an explicit argument. I like to keep my static initialization methods *entirely* free of state, which makes it much easier to reason about which one should happen when (and what variables it assumes have already been created).

So, something like:

```
public class Test {
    public static final Person p = initPerson();
    public static final String pAddress = lookupAddress(p);

    /* implementations of initPerson and lookupAddress omitted */
}
```

It's very clear from looking at that, that (a) you don't need `pAddress` to initialize `p`, and (b) you *do* need `p` to initialize `lookupAddress`. In fact, the compiler would give you a compilation error ("illegal forward reference") if you tried them in reverse order and your static fields were non-`final`:

```
public static String pAddress = lookupAddress(p); // ERROR
public static Person p = initPerson();
```

You would lose that clarity and safety with static blocks. This compiles just fine:

```
static {
    pAddress = p.findAddressSomehow();
    p = new Person();
}
```

... but it'll fail at run time, since at `p.findAddressSomehow()`, `p`  has its default value of `null`.

Comment: so to sum up both the static block and static initilization part will be executed only once is what you mean right

Comment: It's not just the name of the block, the inversion of control is also essential: the method just *returns* the value whereas the init block pushes it into the variable. Since the static type system guarantees that the method will return the value, this promotes readability and correctness. The init block may or may not do the assignment and there is no tight association between the init block and the variable.

Comment: +1 for the additional point on the value of explicit data flow, especially in class initialization code.

Answer (score 3):

A static method (second example) is executed every time you call it. A static init block (first example) is only called once on initializing the class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

> The advantage of private static methods is that they can be reused later if you need to reinitialize the class variable.

This does not count for `final` instances, because a final variable can only be initialized once.

Comment: Except that in this case, the static method is private (meaning only this class can invoke it) and only invoked once, at class initialization.

Comment: I saw your edit, but in this case, the variable is `final` -- so it can't be reinitialized.

Comment: ok, it is private. But it will also execute every time you call it. Also 0 time is possible if you forget to call it. In the example it is never called but I think this was a mistake.

Comment: Yes, it will execute every time you call it -- which in the OP's second example is exactly once, as part of the initializing the class, during `public static final Person p = initPerson();` And in the OP's first example, the `static { ... }` block will be invoked exactly once, as part of initializing the class.

Answer (score 1):

initPerson requires calling at some point, whereas the static block is executed when creating the Test object.

Comment: The static block is executed when first initializing the class, _not_ every time you create a Test object. And the `initPerson` method would be invoked then, too, since it's used to initialize a static field.

Answer (score 1):

The static before a function specifies that you can use that function by calling it on the Class name handle itself. For example, if you want to create a Person object outside the class you can write

```
Person p = Test.initPerson();
```

However, there is no advantageous difference between the two as you can access the object p outside the class in both cases.